# UITextField with two rounded corner

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there any way to create `UItextField` with two corner (left above , right above corner ) rounded??

Answer (score 1):

try to this :

Make a background images and set the custom UItextfield  background images.

Comment: i dont have background image . i want to do it using layer property.